# Is a holomorphic function one to one in the interior of the unit disk necessarily one to one on its boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is a holomorphic function defined in a neighborhood of the unit disk; is it true that if $f$ is 1-1 inside the unit disk $f$ will be 1-1 on the boundary?

I want to use the open mapping theorem to prove that this is true.

Suppose that two points on the boundary are sent to the same point, then they will have neighborhoods the image of which overlap each other, but the overlapping part can come entirely from outside the unit disk, so this argument will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about $f:z\mapsto \exp\left(\pi z\right)$? Isn't it one-to-one inside the disk, but $f(-i)=f(i)=-1$?

Edit: Suppose $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$, so $e^{\pi z_1}=e^{\pi z_2}$. Then $e^{\pi(z_1-z_2)}=1$, so $\pi(z_1-z_2)=2k\pi i$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $z_1$ and $z_2$ differ by some multiple of $2i$, but no two points inside the unit disk are that far apart.

Comment: Why is it one-to-one in the unit disk?

Comment: Well, the exponential function is periodic in the imaginary direction with period $2\pi i$. I'll try to write up a proof, though.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you!